# Stopping time random walk in a circle

Tags: probability, probability-theory, circles, markov-chains, stopping-times

I've been trying to solve this question for some time now, and I could not figure out the second part of the exercise. Here it is:

Consider a circle with five markings 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, in that order. Suppose that a particle starts at state 0 and moves to state 1 or 4 with probability 1/2 each. Subsequent movements are to one of its neighbors with equal probability. Let $X_{n}$ be the state of the particle at time $n \geq 0$. Let

$$ 
\tau = \min \{n \geq 1: X_{n}=0 \} \text{ and } V_{3} = \sum_{n=1}^{\tau}I(X_{n}=3)
$$

a) Compute $E(\tau)$

b) Compute $E(V_{3})$

For part (a) I'm using that $X_{n}$ is an irreducible Markov chain with finite number of states $S = \{0,1,2,3,4\}$. It follows this chain is positive-recurrent and has a unique stationary distribution, which is

$$
\pi = \left( \frac{1}{|S|},\dots,\frac{1}{|S|} \right)
$$

The mean recurrence time for any of the states is then

$$
\mu_{i} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{|S|}} = |S|, i \in S
$$

From this I got $E[\tau] = |S| = 5$ since $\tau$ is the time it takes to go back to state 0 after the chain started there. I wonder how can I solve this using recurrence, like in similar Markov chain problems.

For part (b) I thought about using total expectation but I'm not sure how to move forward. This is what I have so far

$$
E[V_{3}] = E[E[V_{3}|\tau=t]] = E \left[E \left[ \left. \sum_{n=1}^{\tau}I(X_{n}=3) \right| \tau=t\right] \right] =  E\left[ \sum_{n=1}^{\tau}P(X_{n} = 3) \right]
$$

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**EDIT:** I added my attempt for an answer using @Joe suggestions. Let me know if you have any comments.

Comment: I just answered another question with an answer that could be used to solve this one, with some modifications. Basically, you could model your chain as starting in either state 1 or state 4 (with equal probability), and consider state 0 to be absorbing, and compute the expected number of times to visit state 3.  See if this answer helps: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4197772/693577

Comment: @Joe Thank you very much for including important information in your biography about asking questions on site. I hope people will benefit from reading these.

Comment: @TeresaLisbon, I hope so too. It's great to see good questions like this one from newcomers.

Comment: @Joe. I added my attempt for an answer following your suggestions. I think it is correct, but would you mind checking it out?

Comment: It looks good to me. It arrives at the same answer for part (a) also, since starting at either state 1 or state 4, the expected number of steps before absorption is $(2/5)(1+2+3+4)=4$. Adding 1 (since you start at state 0) gives $E[\tau]=5$. It's ok to answer your own question on this site, but I believe it's preferred to make it an answer (instead of part of the post).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is my attempt on a solution based on @Joe suggestions.

Rearranging the transition matrix with the transient states first, i.e., 1-4 and thinking about state 0 as an absorbing state we get

$$
P =
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 & 1/2 \\
 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

We need o compute the fundamental matrix $N = (I_{4}-Q)^{-1}$, where $I_{4}$ is the identity matrix and

$$
Q =
\begin{pmatrix}
 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 0 \\
 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
 0 & 1/2 & 0 & 1/2 \\
 0 & 0 & 1/2 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Computing the fundamental matrix we have

$$
N =
(I_{4}-Q)^{-1} =
\frac{2}{5}
\begin{pmatrix}
 4& 3 & 2 & 1 \\
 3 & 6 & 4 & 2 \\
 2 & 4 & 6 & 3 \\
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now, since $N_{ij}$ is the expected number of times the chain will visit transient state $j$ if it started in transient state $i$ we have

$$
\begin{equation}
 \begin{aligned}
  E[V_{3}|X_{1}=1] = \frac{4}{5} \\
  E[V_{3}|X_{1}=4] = \frac{6}{5}
 \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
$$

Finally, since $P(X_{1}=1) = P(X_{1}=4) = 1/2$ we have

$$
E[V_{3}] = E[V_{3}|X_{1}=1] P(X_{1}=1) + E[V_{3}|X_{1}=4] P(X_{1}=4)
= \frac{4}{5} \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{6}{5} \left( \frac{1}{2}\right) = 1
$$

I think it makes sense to expect the chain to visit state 3 just one time since the expected number of steps before being absorbed at 0 are just 5.

Comment: This is just all round brillliant, I hope more questions will follow this example. +1 for both question and answer.